# How to Add Multiple Font to Single EditText Mean Each Word have Different Font Based on Run time

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, android-typeface

Hi i need to add multiple font to each word enter in edittext , mean every word have different font , i done some of the work with below code .

```
SpannableStringBuilder SS = new 
SpannableStringBuilder(enterword.getText().toString());
SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, size , 
Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
enterword.setText(SS);
```

but this one is working when you have manually assign the text .
also i attach image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUmjb.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to do it in an `EditText` since it's editable. One approach you can take is - add a `TextWatcher` or `onTextChangedListener` to your `EditText`.

Override `afterTextChanged` of the `TextWatcher` and add a custom logic such as following.

```
String[] words = text.split();
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for (String word in words) {
    SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString(word);
    spanned.setSpan( -- your font span here --);
    sb.append(spanned);
    sb.append(" ");
}

editText.setText(sb);
```

You have to add your own logic when and how you want to convert it. When you call `editText.setText`, `afterTextChanged` will get triggered. You need to take care of that recursion using some flag and `handler` for callbacks.

You could have something like this.

```
class FontWatcher(private val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {
    private val handler = Handler()
    private var locked = false

    private val updateCallback = Runnable {
        locked = true
        // Create your spannable as mentioned above
        editText.setText(sb, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
        editText.setSelection(sb.length)
        locked = false
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        if (!locked) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateCallback)
            handler.postDelayed(updateCallback, 300)
        }
    }
}
```

This is not optimized, but should help you get started.